# I can't unwrap very complicated meshes

Tags: uv

I can't unwrap very complicated meshes, for instance, think a spaceship or a car. When I add seams and unwrap, everything turns really small and close even though I am sure I unwrapped well. After I export it to unreal engine, unfortunately my object gets "bad UV error" and shades compiling weird. I thought to split some parts unwrap differently than import. That sounds really good because I can reduce triangles with duplicate-linked but in the Unreal Engine they are just separating and I have to rearrange their position in the scene. Is there something I have been doing wrong unwrapping complex objects, or is there a way to export multiple meshes as to keep object transform in the unreal engine?

As you see the picture, the sofa consists of different parts. I exported this 3dsmax datasmith which the complete scene exports as unreal level and all different object's location and transforms are preserved.

Note: Please don't say are you sure you have unwrapped correct ? I accured this issues almost every complex object, on the other hand it doesn't happen less complicated objects.

[image]

[image]

For instance, I need to make sails different object and UV, use it inside the unreal engine with same location and transformation. Object is joined together except sails.

Comment: Can you show the objects you are mentioning (car, ship...) and their current UVs so we can better understand the issue they have?

Comment: I don't know how to attach picture here so I edited the question

Comment: I found the solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YOizxwI8xA 10.33